# Subcollection resource variable in Firestore Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `tasks` collection in firestore. `Tasks` have subcollections titled `subtasks`. Both tasks and subtasks have an `owner` field.
I have the following Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    match /tasks/{task} {
      allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
      allow create: if isSignedIn();
    
        match /subtasks/{subtask} {
            allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The `match /tasks/{task}` works as expected with checking the auth uid against `resource.data.owner`. To avoid an extra get() charge I am storing the owner on the subtasks as well.

Why does `request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner` throw `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` when attempting to retrieve a subtask?

**Edit:**
It also might be of important to reference how I am querying documents:

```
const subtasksSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "tasks/" + taskId + "/subtasks"));
                
subtasksSnapshot.forEach((subtask) => {
    console.log(subtask.data());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
await getDocs(collection(db, "tasks/" + taskId + "/subtasks"));
```

When you run the above query, it also includes documents where `owner` is not current user. Security rules do not filter out data. You must filter out documents with given constraints yourself. Try running the following query:

```js
const q = query(collection(db, "tasks/" + taskId + "/subtasks"), where("owner", "==", CURRENT_USER_ID))

const subtasksSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

Additionally, do ensure that user is logged in before running the query.